# Sorting algorithm complexity

Tags: javascript, algorithm

The array of natural numbers (up to and including n), passed to "findMissed" function. The numbers in array are unordered and each number occurs once. Вut one number is missing. I need to determine which one is missed and return it. **For the computational complexity to be O(n)**.

Can I use JS sort() function in solution, and then "for"

```
function findMissed(arr) {
  arr.sort();
  for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
    ...
  }
}
```

or it will be more complex than O(n)?

Comment: Yes you can. But the javascript `sort` function does not work the way you think it does. Check the section about comparing numbers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Sort is in general `O(n log(n))` and therefore is not `O(n)`.  See the linked story for how to do it.

Comment: If each element is unique, I would create two sets and return the difference. Here are a few ways: https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/javascript/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-javascript.html